# Asp.Net web farm IIS on EC2 and ELBs

Tags: iis, asp.net, load-balancing, web, web-farm

I'm a developer now developing my startup. I really don't know much about IIS setup. I will host my startup on Amazon EC2. And I want to know how can I scale my application if my traffic increase. I been reading about MS Deploy and  Web Farm Framework here: [IIS Configuration Synchronization for Web Server Farm?](https://serverfault.com/questions/127409/iis-configuration-synchronization-for-web-server-farm) . And I want a simple architecture, with not to much configuration. So I been looking an experience with an IIS web farm and Amazon ELBs. And I did not find any one.

So the question is:

- It is possible to make a IIS web farm with Amazon ELBs?
- Any experience on Ec2 on this?
- What you recommend for an easy web farm setup with IIS adn Amazon tools?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://appharbor.com They provide web application hosting (IIS) with automatic deployment and scaling is as easy as setting a number of instances (much like Azure). So no hassle with setting up servers etc