# IIS Content and Configuration Sync

Tags: windows, iis, web-server, replication

We have a Web Farm with IIS 7.5 that has a 3rd party application that syncs IIS Content and Configuration.  We used this back in IIS 6 days, when there were no tools in the OS that handled this easily.  The software is nice, but it has become buggy.

This link provides a lot of good pros/cons of each method that we can use from Microsoft. 
[IIS Configuration Synchronization for Web Server Farm?](https://serverfault.com/questions/127409/iis-configuration-synchronization-for-web-server-farm)

Questions:

1. For Server 2016 and IIS 10, is Shared Configuration and IIS Web Farm Framework 2.2 still preferred and supported method of syncing IIS Content and Configuration?  I have read over these subjects and I haven't found a place that says both of these are still supported means of IIS 10 replication.
2. For our current load balance, each website is balanced with a dedicated IP address that is unique to that server.  That is the endpoint of the balance.  For example: Site1 on server 1 = x.x.x.100, Site 1 on Server 2 = x.x.x.101, etc.  We've been able to avoid Host Headers this way.
   The 3rd party IIS sync software we are using supports adding binding overrides during the sync job, so I can specify what bindings I want on what servers in the sync.  I don't see this option in Shared Configuration or IIS Web Farm Framework 2.2.  How do people load balance websites without this?